# Access and set variables from Struct/Array in ColdFusion

Tags: arrays, data-structures, coldfusion, struct

I have the following structure and what I'm trying to do is set variables for the different keys in it (personaID,personaName,userClubList) and then set variables for the values within the userClubList array but don't know how to work my way down through the structure, finding out which keys it has and then what the values of they keys are.

[image: CF Struct]
!

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What's the end goal? You can access the variables with something like `userAccountInfo.Personas[1].personaID = 'blahblah'` and so forth, but that assumes you know the structure of the data you're getting.

Comment: You can access the first clubAbbr in userClubList like: `userAccountInfo.personas[1].userClubList[1].clubAbbr`

Comment: to find out what keys a structure has use StructKeyList or StructKeyArray.  You can then loop over this

Comment: Are these values being set from a query? Are you trying to change the values or display the values? As Busches said, what's the goal here?

Comment: Also, what version of ColdFusion are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are already able to work with this structure and do not require any mapping to additional variables. Access to structures is done by using the dot notation `userAccountInfo.personas` or by square brackets `userAccountInfo["personas"]`. You can access any structure depth by chaining the access `userAccountInfo.personas[1].userClubList[1].clubAbbr`. Usually you would want to check the existence of all these structure members, especially the arrays, by using `structKeyExists(userAccountInfo, "personas")` or `isDefined("userAccountInfo.personas")` (isDefined is not recommended due to its lax way of handling scopes though). You would chain these as well by passing the next member on each check `structKeyExists(userAccountInfo.personas[1], "userClubList")` and then `structKeyExists(userAccountInfo.personas[1].userClubList[1], "clubAbbr")` and so on.

Anyway, in order to guide you some more, here's my understanding of your structure:

```
<!--- test data (the one in your screenshot) --->
<cfset userAccountInfo = {}>
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas = []>
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas[1] = {}>
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas[1].personaId = "850074729">
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas[1].personaName = "IcedTube3">
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas[1].userClubList = []>
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas[1].userClubList[1] = {}>
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas[1].userClubList[1].clubAbbr = "Bel">
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas[1].userClubList[1].clubName = "Bell Ville FC">
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas[1].userClubList[1].established = "1363092161">
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas[1].userClubList[1].lastAccessTime = "1363092161">
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas[1].userClubList[1].platform = "360">
<cfset userAccountInfo.personas[1].userClubList[1].year = "2013">

<!--- let's make sure personas exists and is an array --->
<cfif structKeyExists(userAccountInfo, "personas") and isArray(userAccountInfo.personas)> 

    <cfset myPersonas = userAccountInfo.personas> <!--- myPersonas will be an array --->
    <cfloop array="#myPersonas#" index="persona"> <!--- persona is supposed to be a struct --->

        <!--- let's make sure each item in the array is really a struct --->
        <cfif isStruct(persona)>

            <cfoutput>Start reading persona.<br />====================<br /><br /></cfoutput>

            <!--- read personaId --->
            <cfif structKeyExists(persona, "personaId")>
                <cfoutput>personaId: #persona.personaId#<br /></cfoutput>
            <cfelse>
                <cfoutput>personaId: [none]<br /></cfoutput>
            </cfif>

            <!--- read personaName --->
            <cfif structKeyExists(persona, "personaName")>
                <cfoutput>personaName: #persona.personaName#<br /></cfoutput>
            <cfelse>
                <cfoutput>personaName: [none]<br /></cfoutput>
            </cfif>

            <!--- read userClubList (let's make sure userClubList exists in persona and is an array) --->
            <cfif structKeyExists(persona, "userClubList") and isArray(persona.userClubList) and not arrayIsEmpty(persona.userClubList)>

                <cfset myUserClubList = persona.userClubList>
                <cfloop array="#myUserClubList#" index="club"> <!--- club is supposed to be a struct --->

                    <!--- let's make sure each item in the array is really a struct --->
                    <cfif isStruct(club)>

                        <cfoutput><br />Start reading club.<br />--------------------<br /><br /></cfoutput>

                        <!--- read clubAbbr --->
                        <cfif structKeyExists(club, "clubAbbr")>
                            <cfoutput>clubAbbr: #club.clubAbbr#<br /></cfoutput>
                        <cfelse>
                            <cfoutput>clubAbbr: [none]<br /></cfoutput>
                        </cfif>

                        <!--- and so on... --->

                        <cfoutput><br />--------------------<br />Done reading club.<br /><br /></cfoutput>

                    </cfif>

                </cfloop>

            <cfelse>
                <cfoutput>userClubList: [none]<br /></cfoutput>
            </cfif>

            <cfoutput><br />====================<br />Done reading persona.<br /><br /></cfoutput>

        </cfif>

    </cfloop>

</cfif>
```

Results in...

```
Start reading persona.
====================

personaId: 850074729
personaName: IcedTube3

Start reading club.
--------------------

clubAbbr: Bel

--------------------
Done reading club.


====================
Done reading persona.
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: One of the best laid out examples of out to test, loop, and check for structures, arrays and various combinations of nest items. With your sample of code above, I was able to write my own loop/checking function. Too bad CPB07 never came back to mark this as correct. It really is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

Really this will all depend on what your final goal is. Looking at the data model that you're showing in your struct above, you are building a single record for a single user account that can have multiple personas that can belong to multiple userClubLists. The code below shows how you can get that populated.

Note: This format will work in CF8+.

```
<cfscript>
 userAccountInfo = {
    userAccountInfo = {
    personas = [ 
            {
            personaID = "850074729",
            personaName = "IcedTube3",
            userClubList =  [
                                {
                                clubAbbr = "Bel",
                                clubName = "Bel Ville FC",
                                established = "1361354191",
                                lastAccessTime = "1363092161",
                                platform = "360",
                                year = "2013"
                                },
                                {
                                clubAbbr = "New",
                                clubName = "New Club",
                                established = "1362139200",
                                lastAccessTime = "1363092161",
                                platform = "720",
                                year = "2012"
                                },
                                {
                                clubAbbr = "Old",
                                clubName = "Old Club",
                                established = "1261255543",
                                lastAccessTime = "1267444800",
                                platform = "180",
                                year = "2005"
                                }
                            ]
            },
            {
            personaID = "499137600",
            personaName = "Marty",
            userClubList =  [
                                {
                                clubAbbr = "Biff",
                                clubName = "BiffCo Casino",
                                established = "307588800",
                                lastAccessTime = "1445390400",
                                platform = "1955a",
                                year = "1985"
                                }
                            ]
            }
        ]
    }
    } ;
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#userAccountInfo#" label="UserAccountInfo" />
```